# Call to a member function prepare() on null sanctun laravel mongodb

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

- Sanctum Version: ^2.12
- Laravel Version: 8.69.0
- PHP Version: 7.4
- Database Driver & Version: mongoDB

#### Description:

After the system was fully set up, everything was working properly. But after the changes for create new token by `$user->createToken('token_base_name')->plainTextToken` keep give me `Call to a member function prepare() on null`.

`personal_access_tokens` table exists but its empty.

```
Schema::create('personal_access_tokens', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->morphs('tokenable');
            $table->string('name'); # OR $table->string('token_base_name'); ->> no changes
            $table->string('token', 64)->unique();
            $table->text('abilities')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('last_used_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: Sounds like you have not connected to the DB

Comment: i do. i can get records from other tables. error is on `createToken` sanctum method
@RiggsFolly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i fixed it, but I had to change Non-project files.

in `vendor/laravel/sanctum/src/PersonalAccessToken.php` for mongoDB must be use use `Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model`

`PersonalAccessToken.php` be like :

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Sanctum\Contracts\HasAbilities;

class PersonalAccessToken extends Model implements HasAbilities
{

 ......
 
}
```

Comment: You had better report that to the developers of that package, you may have done the right thing, but also you may not, and when you upgrade to a new release  you will loose that change

Answer (score 0):

Add a console command to automatically update the **`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`** in the Sanctum vendor files to include **`Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model`** instead.

**Installation**

Move the below code of **MongoDBSanctumFix.php** to **app/Console/Commands**. You may need to create the Commands folder

```
<?php

    namespace App\Console\Commands;

    use Illuminate\Console\Command;

    class MongoDBSanctumFix extends Command {

        protected $signature = 'fix:sanctum
                        {--rollback : Rollback the Sanctum fix}';

        protected $description = 'Fixes sanctum for MongoDB support';

        protected $mongo_model = 'Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model';

        protected $laravel_model = 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model';

        protected $sanctum_path = 'vendor/laravel/sanctum/src/';

        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function handle()
        {
            if (!$this->option('rollback')) {
                $this->fixFiles();
                $this->info("Sanctum Files have been fixed for MongoDB");
            } else {
                $this->rollbackFiles();
                $this->info("Sanctum Files have been rolled back for MongoDB");
            }
        }

        protected function fixFiles() {
            foreach (glob(base_path($this->sanctum_path) . '*.php') as $filename)
            {
                $file = file_get_contents($filename);
                file_put_contents($filename, str_replace($this->laravel_model, $this->mongo_model, $file));
            }
        }

        protected function rollbackFiles()
        {
            foreach (glob(base_path($this->sanctum_path) . '*.php') as $filename)
            {
                $file = file_get_contents($filename);
                file_put_contents($filename, str_replace($this->mongo_model, $this->laravel_model, $file));
            }

        }
}
```

**How to Run**

> Run **php artisan fix:sanctum** to fix the issue.

This will need to be run everytime Laravel Sanctum is updated

> To revert these changes: **php artisan fix:sanctum --rollback**

For Reference, please check: https://github.com/sadnub/laravel-mongodb-passport-fix