# Creating Token with Sanctum in Laravel 10 application that has a mongoDB database, Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: mongodb, laravel-sanctum, laravel-10, laravel-mongodb

I have a laravel 10 application using a mongoDB database, i am creating an API end point to generate token for users in collection api_users.
the following function for creating users works perfectly

```
    public function createApiUser(Request $request)
    {

        // try {
        //     DB::connection('mongodb')->getPdo();   ### this also is successful when enabled
        //     return  ["Connected successfully to the database!"];
        // } catch (\Exception $e) {
        //     die("Could not connect to the database: " . $e->getMessage());
        // }


        $username = $request->input('username');
        $password = $request->input('password');

        $password = Hash::make($password);

        $apiUser = new ApiUser();

        $apiUser->username = $username;
        $apiUser->password = $password;

        try {
            $apiUser->save();
            return ["Success"];
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            //throw $th;

            return ["error" => $th->getMessage()];
        }
    }
```

but when i make a request to generate token using this function

```
 public function generateToken(Request $request)
    {
 
        $username = $request->input('username');
        $password = $request->input('password');
        $collection = DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('api_users');

        // Retrieve the user document based on the username
        $userData = ApiUser::where('username', $username)->first();
 

        // return $userData;  ###this also returns user details successfully when enabled
        if ($userData && Hash::check($password, $userData['password'])) {
            // Create an instance of ApiUser model from the retrieved data
            $user = $userData;


            // return $user;
            // Authentication successful, generate a token for the user
            $token = $user->createToken('MyApp')->plainTextToken; // **####the error is generated then this line is being executed**

            // Return the token to the user as a response
            return response()->json([
                'token' => $token,
                'user' => $user,
            ], 200);
        }

        // Authentication failed, return an error response
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorised'], 401);
    }
```

this is the error message

> Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in file /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 574

and here is the model for ApiUser

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use MongoDB\Laravel\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use MongoDB\Laravel\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
use MongoDB\Laravel\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
// use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;


// class ApiUser extends Eloquent implements Authenticatable
class ApiUser extends Eloquent

{

    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory,Notifiable;
    protected $guard = 'api';
    protected $table = 'api_users'; // Ensure this matches your MongoDB collection name

    protected $connection = 'mongodb'; // Use your MongoDB connection name here
    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'password',
    ];
}
```

and the auth.php guard and providers are these

```
<?php

return [ 
    

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',

        'email' => [ // Add this configuration for email verification
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ], 

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'mongodb' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        // for API

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'sanctum',
            'provider' => 'api_users', // Use the 'api_users' provider for API authentication
        ],

        'api_users' => [
            'driver' => 'sanctum',
            'provider' => 'api_users',
        ],
    ],


    'verification' => [
        'enabled' => false,
        'expire' => 60,
    ], 

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],

        'api_users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\ApiUser::class, // Use the ApiUser model for API authentication
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
 

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],
 
    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

i have tried going through many online resources including Laravel official documentation and still cannot find a solution. i have also tried deleting and recreating the model and controller but i arrive to the same error when it comes to token generation, other endpoints if work fine so far even creation of new records in database.

how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the solution to this and it was by changing vendor file located at `vendor/laravel/sanctum/src/PersonalAccessToken.php` 
I change the statement
`use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;` to `use MongoDB\Laravel\Eloquent\Model;` @sahandi81  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69919109/3463649)